# Element-wise average and standard deviation across multiple dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Data:
Multiple dataframes of the same format (same columns, an equal number of rows, and no points missing).

How do I create a "summary" dataframe that contains an element-wise mean for every element? How about a dataframe that contains an element-wise standard deviation?

```
          A         B         C
0 -1.624722 -1.160731  0.016726
1 -1.565694  0.989333  1.040820
2 -0.484945  0.718596 -0.180779
3  0.388798 -0.997036  1.211787
4 -0.249211  1.604280 -1.100980
5  0.062425  0.925813 -1.810696
6  0.793244 -1.860442 -1.196797

          A         B         C
0  1.016386  1.766780  0.648333
1 -1.101329 -1.021171  0.830281
2 -1.133889 -2.793579  0.839298
3  1.134425  0.611480 -1.482724
4 -0.066601 -2.123353  1.136564
5 -0.167580 -0.991550  0.660508
6  0.528789 -0.483008  1.472787
```

Comment: Can you please provide a few sample data frames?

Comment: `A         B         C
0 -1.624722 -1.160731  0.016726
1 -1.565694  0.989333  1.040820
2 -0.484945  0.718596 -0.180779
3  0.388798 -0.997036  1.211787
4 -0.249211  1.604280 -1.100980
5  0.062425  0.925813 -1.810696
6  0.793244 -1.860442 -1.196797`

`          A         B         C
0  1.016386  1.766780  0.648333
1 -1.101329 -1.021171  0.830281
2 -1.133889 -2.793579  0.839298
3  1.134425  0.611480 -1.482724
4 -0.066601 -2.123353  1.136564
5 -0.167580 -0.991550  0.660508
6  0.528789 -0.483008  1.472787`

Comment: @Alealeale: formatting is lost in comments - please could you edit the example into your question?

Comment: What does it mean element-wise mean and std dev? what does each mean represent as usually mean and std-dev is the mean of a bunch of values and not for each value which is meaningless

Answer (score 6):

You can create a panel of your DataFrames and then compute the mean and SD along the items axis:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 3), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 3), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 3), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
p = pd.Panel({n: df for n, df in enumerate([df1, df2, df3])})

>>> p.mean(axis=0)
          A         B         C
0 -0.024284 -0.622337  0.581292
1  0.186271  0.596634 -0.498755
2  0.084591 -0.760567 -0.334429
3 -0.833688  0.403628  0.013497
4  0.402502 -0.017670 -0.369559
5  0.733305 -1.311827  0.463770
6 -0.941334  0.843020 -1.366963
7  0.134700  0.626846  0.994085
8 -0.783517  0.703030 -1.187082
9 -0.954325  0.514671 -0.370741

>>> p.std(axis=0)
          A         B         C
0  0.196526  1.870115  0.503855
1  0.719534  0.264991  1.232129
2  0.315741  0.773699  1.328869
3  1.169213  1.488852  1.149105
4  1.416236  1.157386  0.414532
5  0.554604  1.022169  1.324711
6  0.178940  1.107710  0.885941
7  1.270448  1.023748  1.102772
8  0.957550  0.355523  1.284814
9  0.582288  0.997909  1.566383
```

Comment: For those using a recent version of pandas, Panel was removed in 0.25.0. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57711312/im-getting-this-error-typeerror-object-takes-no-parameters)

Answer (score 2):

One simple solution here is to simply concatenate the existing dataframes into a single dataframe while adding an ID variable to track the original source:

```
dfa = pd.DataFrame( np.random.randn(2,2), columns=['a','b'] ).assign(id='a')
dfb = pd.DataFrame( np.random.randn(2,2), columns=['a','b'] ).assign(id='b')

df = pd.concat([df1,df2])

          a         b id
0 -0.542652  1.609213  a
1 -0.192136  0.458564  a
0 -0.231949 -0.000573  b
1  0.245715 -0.083786  b
```

So now you have two 2x2 dataframes combined into a single 4x2 dataframe.  The 'id' columns identifies the source dataframe so you haven't lost any generality, and can select on 'id' to do the same thing you would to any single dataframe.  E.g. `df[ df['id'] == 'a' ]`.

But now you can also use `groupby` to do any pandas method such as `mean()` or `std()` on an element by element basis:

```
df.groupby('id').mean()

              a         b
index                    
0      0.198164 -0.811475
1      0.639529  0.812810
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be grouping on the index instead of id? Grouping by id only computes the intra-dataframe average.

Comment: @RaphaelD. Perhaps.  I was merely trying to show that the combination of concatenation + groupby is very flexible and will let you easily do a variety of things, including what you suggest.

Comment: I understand. You answer was really helpful in my case, especially since the other one isn't working with my version of Pandas. I just intended to give additional details for future readers.

Comment: @RaphaelD.  No problem, glad this was helpful and feel free to edit my answer if you think you can improve it.  It's a long time ago that I answered it, and not very fresh in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked for me.

```
average_data_frame = (dataframe1 + dataframe2 ) / 2
```

Or, if you have more than two dataframes, say *n*, then

```
average_data_frame = dataframe1
for i in range(1,n):
    average_data_frame = average_data_frame + i_th_dataframe
average_data_frame = average_data_frame / n
```

Once you have the average, you can go for the standard deviation. If you are looking for a "true Pythonic" approach, you should follow other answers. But if you are looking for a working and quick solution, this is it.