# i"m getting this error: TypeError: object() takes no parameters

Tags: python, pandas, panel

I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: object() takes no parameters

My code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = np.random.rand(2, 4, 5)
p = pd.Panel(data)
```

I expect the output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 2 (items) x 4 (major_axis) x 5 (minor_axis)
Items axis: 0 to 1
Major_axis axis: 0 to 3
Minor_axis axis: 0 to 4
```

Comment: i had already imported the numpy library as np

Comment: Please add the full error stack to your question.

Comment: Cannot reproduce; `pd.Panel(data)` produces a warning about `Panel` being deprecated, but `repr(p)` produces the string you expect.

Comment: @chepner you cant reproduce because he is using a newer version in which it doesnt exist anymore.. on the right track though

Comment: Even after upgrading to 0.25, `Panel` still seems to exist, though the `TypeError` specifically mentions `Panel` (not `object`) as taking no arguments. (Maybe the dev 0.26 version is different?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the pandas.Panel deprecation warning actually recommending?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482256/what-is-the-pandas-panel-deprecation-warning-actually-recommending)

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a recent version of pandas, you will find that Panel has been [removed](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/panel.html).

> Panel was removed in 0.25.0. For prior documentation, see the 0.24 documentation

This [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482256/what-is-the-pandas-panel-deprecation-warning-actually-recommending) explains the recommended alternative.